# Sums of Kronecker products of elements of one list with elements from another list in R

Tags: r, list

I am not sure how to explain what I want to do in such a way that gives meaningful answers from a search in Google. For this reason, I am also not sure the best way to title this question, so my apologies if the title is unclear.

Suppose I have two lists of matrices called `a` and `B`. `a` is a list of column matrices, all of the same size. `B` is a list of square matrices, all of the same size. Each list has the same length.

```
> a <- list( t(t(c(1,2,3))), t(t(c(-2,1,2))) )
> a
[[1]]
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    2
[3,]    3

[[2]]
     [,1]
[1,]   -2
[2,]    1
[3,]    2

> B <- list( diag(2), diag(c(1,3)) )
> B
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    0
[2,]    0    1

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    0
[2,]    0    3
```

My goal is to produce a new list, say `C`, where the first element is a matrix defined by

`a[[1]][1]*B[[1]] + a[[2]][1]*B[[2]]`, the second element is a matrix defined by

`a[[1]][2]*B[[1]] + a[[2]][2]*B[[2]]`, and the third element is a matrix defined by

`a[[1]][3]*B[[1]] + a[[2]][3]*B[[2]]`. The length of the list `C` is equal to the length of a column matrix in `a`. So in this example, `C` should be a list of length 3.

This looks like the sum of Kronecker products (hence my title) so I have tried

```
kronecker(a[[1]], B[[1]]) + kronecker(a[[2]], B[[2]])
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   -1    0
[2,]    0   -5
[3,]    3    0
[4,]    0    5
[5,]    5    0
[6,]    0    9
```

This gives a matrix that contains the proper numbers, but the result is not a list. I don't think this is a problem as I should be able to convert the output into the desired list. The problem is I'm not sure of how to generalize it for when the column matrices in `a` have a length of, say, 10 or 100.

Working on a solution I created a for-loop.

```
C <- list()
for (i in 1:length(a[[1]])) {
    C[[i]] = a[[1]][i]*B[[1]] + a[[2]][i]*B[[2]]
}
> C
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   -1    0
[2,]    0   -5

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    0
[2,]    0    5

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    0
[2,]    0    9
```

This gives me exactly what I want for this particular example, but I'm not sure of a way to generalize this for-loop either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code generalizes the kronecker products' sum and then splits the result.

The original code is

```
lst <- lapply(seq_along(a), function(i) kronecker(a[[i]], B[[i]]))
res <- Reduce(`+`, lst)
```

But following a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62364382/sums-of-kronecker-products-of-elements-of-one-list-with-elements-from-another-li/62364525#comment110304072_62364525) of user [G. Grothendieck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/516548/g-grothendieck), this can be written as

```
res <- Reduce("+", Map(kronecker, a, B))
```

Then, split the results matrix.

```
split.data.frame(res, rep(seq_along(a[[1]]), each = length(a)))
#$`1`
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]   -1    0
#[2,]    0   -5
#
#$`2`
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    3    0
#[2,]    0    5
#
#$`3`
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    5    0
#[2,]    0    9
```

And now that the temporary list `lst` is no longer needed,

```
rm(lst)    # final clean-up
```

As a final note, the `split.data.frame` method must be explicitly called. From the documentation of `?split`, section Details, my emphasis:

> split and split<- are generic functions with default and data.frame
>   methods. **The data frame method can also be used to split a matrix into
>   a list of matrices**, and the replacement form likewise, provided they
>   are invoked explicitly.

If the **default method** is used, the matrix will be split as if it were a vector and the `dim` attribute will be dropped.

Comment: The first two lines can be written as `Reduce("+", Map(kronecker, a, B))`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Thanks, I forgot about `Map`. Edited.

Comment: @RuiBarradas - many thanks for the answer. I just now realized that the output is not proper. The output should have three elements and each element should be a 2x2 matrix.

Comment: I've already given a "+1" but I wish I could give another for the bit about using `rm()` to clean up. It's been incredibly useful.

Comment: `split.data.frame(res, rep(seq_along(a[[1]]), each = length(seq_along(a))))` seems to do the trick.

Comment: @SOULed_Outt `length(seq_along(a))` and `length(a)` return the same value since `seq_along` returns consecutive indices into `a` (as many as elements of `a`).

Comment: @RuiBarradas - Understood.

Comment: @RuiBarradas - The code `split.data.frame(res, rep(seq_along(a[[1]]), each = length(a)))` seems to give the desire output of a list of length 3. Would you kindly update your answer?

Comment: @SOULed_Outt Done, see now.